# How should I access a samba share?

Tags: networking, server, mount, lubuntu, samba

I have setup a samba share on a desktop computer & need to access it from my laptop. If I use File manager PCManFM--Go--network--Windows Network--WORKGROUP, I get (Failed to retrieve share list from server:Connection timed out)--(The specified location is not mounted). I installed the samba share using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21           Both server & client are lubuntu 16.04 LTS

martyn@martyn-ESPRIMO-Mobile-V5535:~$ smbclient -L //192.168.0.13 -U martyn
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter martyn's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
Shared          Disk      
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (martyn-M830LU server (Samba, Ubuntu))
Deskjet_1050_J410 Printer   Deskjet_1050_J410
```

Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

```
Server               Comment
---------            -------
MARTYN-M830LU        martyn-M830LU server (Samba, Ubuntu)

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            MARTYN-M830LU
```

martyn@martyn-ESPRIMO-Mobile-V5535:~$

Comment: What happens if you run smbclient -L //server -U user replacing //server with your server name and user with your user credentials for the server?

Comment: run smbclient -L //server -U user gives no sensible return using server name but does return results using IP address.                                                             Results added above.

Comment: I have managed to get it to work by replacing (smb://WORKGROUP/) with        (smb://192.168.0.13/) when searching within PCManFM file manager. Why does it come up with WORKGROUP when I search Network? What am I doing wrong?